# Pandas group times into hour periods and count

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe where I have created a column called `newTime` which is based on the `time` from a `dateTime` column called `InvoiceDate`.

```
df['newTime'] = [d.time() for d in df['InvoiceDate']]
```

In this column is a list of times using the format `HH:mm:ss`

How do I group these times into hour periods for a full 24 hours and then get a count for each period?

So the dataframe column looks like:

[image: Dataframe]

And the expected output looks like the following (or similar):

[image: expected output]

Comment: Is possible add some sample data and expected output?

Comment: @jezrael  added, apologies.

Comment: No problem, changed solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need aggregate [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) by [`hour`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.hour.html)s:

```
df1 = df.groupby(df['InvoiceDate'].dt.hour).size().reset_index(name='count')
```

Comment: so I dont even need my newTime column?

Comment: @Silentbob - No, it is not necessary, because it possible extract hours.